# Rebrand overflow: Should we have a new name for community content?

Tags: discussion, community, arqade-migration, branding

Currently, community content is loosely branded as 'Stack Gaming'. And we have a blue heart logo based on the soon-to-be-(almost)-extinct red pixel heart. With the Arqade rebrand, should we come up with a new name and logo for our community content?

Comment: I can't find any decent synonyms for Arcade, but I think something that ties in would be nice, e.g. Insert Coin.

Comment: QAmmunity QAntent. :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drawing from the creative spark of @GnomeSlice, here is another logo concept.

[image: ARRRRRRRQAde]
[image: ARQADE2]
[image: Arqade3]

Here is the same version as the above, but cropped and without the light-blue shadow (as per @GnomeSlicE and @James suggestions).

[image: Arqade3a]

One [SVG](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByaM9NGpK0HnRjdVTk00c0gwSnM) and the other [SVG](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByaM9NGpK0HnM2lkRjl4WWYzNm8) in case you want to mess around with them. Here is the [SVG](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByaM9NGpK0HnVlItRll2SnhJV3M) for the third one. Here is the cropped [SVG](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByaM9NGpK0HnazVWVHZEeklKNWc) without the light-blue "shadow" bit.

**[Here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByaM9NGpK0Hnam1HUTFWVGo4QjA) is an archived zip of the final .ai file and the fonts for the logo.**

Let me know if you want me to make any changes (different size, orientation, etc.) or need anything else. Or if there are any areas that need improvement.

Comment: I might post the ones you took the basic idea from at some point, but this is pretty much better in every way, nice work.

Comment: I hate the blurry text in the 2nd and particularly 3rd one. Really like the 4th one though.

Answer (score 6):

If we do decide to do this, please remember our Facebook page is permanently stuck as https://www.facebook.com/StackGaming, the youtube channel cannot be changed from GamingSE and our email will always be StackGaming@gmail.com amongst other things.

I also don't think this is necessary seeing as this is still the **gaming** site for **Stack** exchange.

Comment: Steam is also stuck.

Comment: Thats a damn shame. But maybe we should update the logos?

Comment: We can always make another youtube channel, and facebook page is we have to.  I think it's in our best interests to have something that actually matches the name of the site, and people aren't going to immediately know what 'gaming SE' or 'stackgaming' refer to, I don't think.

Comment: I was of the same opinion, but merging everything is gonna be a pain. But hey, better do it right now than wait! I also suggest we get the ArqadeCommunity handle on twitter right now.

Comment: @Fredy31 Done so for if we decide to change.

Comment: Do we have numbers on how much traffic those pages actually get? Being "stuck" with them is really only an issue if more than like 20 people are visiting them, which has sort of been my current impression of those sites.

Answer (score 5):

I think, [if it's ok with SE](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4932/3610), we should use the heart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I spent most of today coming up with a design for the community to use as a logo.  Long story short, it turned out rather terribly.[image: Proposed logo for the community]

I've got some other ideas kicking around, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: Top left seems more fitting. But I would put the ar and de smaller, same size as the QA.

Comment: Have the text in the same perspective as the cabinet