# Dear Stack Exchange: Can we have the heart?

Tags: support, community, branding

Now that you have retired the heart logo from the site, can the community have the right to use it as a badge for our community content? This would cover things like videos, or anything the community wishes to 'brand'.

Whether or not the community wants to use it is still [under discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4846/3610), but it would be good to know if we have this option.

Yours,
The community formerly known as Gaming.

Comment: We should all have a heart.

Comment: @JohntheGreen What if I don't want a heart?

Comment: @Origami Then don't go see the wizard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that the heart is no longer our official logo, I don't see any reason why you can't use it to "brand" community generated content off the site. Just keep in mind that our company policy is that you can't use our official logos or name. But it's fine if you want to refer to community pages as "The Arqade Community" or something similar. "Arqade Lovers" was suggested somewhere I believe ;-)

Jin said he will get you the vector file soon, so stay tuned.

Comment: **I suggested Arqade Lovers**.  I want full credit for it.

Comment: @DavidFullerton As much as it pains me to admit it, Arqanoids is the best possible community name.